# How to display Child form on the top of all elements of MDI form

Tags: c#, vb.net, parent-child, mdi, dock

I have created a MDI form and also a Child form. However my MDI form contains a ribbon menu docked in top, sidebar docked in left and a Panel container docked to be filled.

Now when i am invoking the child form, it gets shown behind all theses MDI docked controls.

And when after showing the child form if i make the `panel_container1.visible = false` the child form gets shown at that place.

I don't want to keep other controls visibility set to false and then again to true.

Is there any way that automatically the child form comes on the top of all these docked items?

Comment: Everything must be docked to an edge.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by docked to an edge? Either it could be `Top`, `Right`, `Left`, `Fill`, `Bottom` or `None`.

Comment: Top, Right, Left and Bottom are the edges.  Fill and None cannot work, that overlaps the dark-gray MDI client window.